# Is it possible to edit elasticsearch snapshots

Tags: elasticsearch

I have recently started working on a project where I need to deal with elastic search.
Being new to this technology, I m little uncomfortable in taking decisions in scenarios like below.

1. I do see some of the snapshots of the cluster are empty, due to which my data presentation modules are showing zigzag lines. I know that empty snapshots introduced do to wrongly reindexing the indexes from existing indexes.
2. For some snapshots the data is duplicated in it due to the fact that same index was copied twice into the snap shot, which again causing zigzag nature of the graphs on my data presentation module.

So what I want to know is if I have snapshots called A, B, C, D.
All are derived from A, but unfortunately B is empty(due to some logic issue data was not copied from A to B) and D is double of A in size(duplicates introduced).
I want to make B as a copy of A and D as copy of C.

Can someone suggest me how to attack this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Also will it be possible to find duplicates in snapshots and delete those?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth touching on this before looking at your questions

snapshots of the same indices, in the same repository, are incremental - as long as the segments of the indices do not change

that means that if the segments of these indices don't change over time, then Elasticsearch can tell that there's been no changes and so won't duplicate the data. if there are changes made, then a new snapshot will be taken

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/snapshot-restore.html has more on that, and https://steve-mushero.medium.com/how-elasticsearch-snapshots-work-3824fdfc4493 is also a good read

to answer your direct questions, we'd need to understand a little more on what you are doing between these snapshots, and what you are seeing when you say there was a "logic issue", and again for the "duplicates introduced" comment